# Enumeration parameter for SOAP WS in JAX WS

Tags: java, jax-ws

I would like to ask how can i specify to SOAP Web services in **JAX-WS**, Such that if i want a field to be filled either by value `A` or value `B`. Any other value should return an error.

I thought of enumerations in Java but still didn't figure out how to implement it.

Any Suggestions? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use enumerations for the same.

In your XSD for the WSDL, you will define the element like below:-

```
 <xsd:complexType name="Value">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="elementValue" type="constantType" />
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>


<xsd:simpleType name="constantType">
  <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
    <xsd:enumeration value="A" />
    <xsd:enumeration value="B" />
  </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

In above example you are saying that there is an element with name elementValue which is of constantType, constantType can either have value of A or B  which  are of type String.

When you talk about SOAP, basically WSDL is a contract which you will need to share with your service user. If a particular field can have only two values then this should be mentioned in your contract i.e. WSDL.

In java you can use Enum to define this like below:-

```
public enum ElementValue
{
  A,
  B;
}
```

Now you can access these values with below syntax:-

```
ElementValue.A
ElementValue.B
```

Comment: Hey Amit Thank you for your response, actually i generate the wsdl from java code, so i would like to know how to do what you mentionned with jax ws annotations this is my real issue. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

if you use the annotation [XmlEnum](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlEnum.html) on your Java Enum the resulting WSDL contains the simple type. An example can be found [in the documentation for XmlEnumValue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlEnumValue.html)

```
@XmlEnum
public enum ElementValue
{
    A,
    B;
}
```

results in the following WSDL part:

```
 <xs:simpleType name="ElementValue">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
       <xs:enumeration value="A"/>
       <xs:enumeration value="B"/>             
    </xs:restriction
 </xs:simpleType>
```